# Changing to swift 3. Line of code now returns immutable value error

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, immutability, xcode8

I have recently made the conversion to swift 3 on my game at first there was about 10 errors but I have managed to get that down to one. I have been looking around for about 3 hours and nothing has worked for me so any help will be much appreciated.

Here is my issue:

```
for i:CGFloat in 0 ..< 2.0 + self.frame.size.width / ( groundTexture.size().width * 2.0 ) += 1 {
        let sprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: groundTexture)
        sprite.setScale(3.0)
        sprite.position = CGPoint(x: i * sprite.size.width, y: sprite.size.height / 2)
        sprite.run(moveGroundSpritesForever)
        moving.addChild(sprite)
    }
```

The first line of code here gives this error:

```
GameScene.swift:105:99: Left side of mutating operator isn't mutable: '..<' returns immutable value
```

I am on Xcode 8 if this helps.
Once again any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this loop statement?

Comment: That's probably the most unclear LOC I've ever seen